Getting coverage from Github action qemu
I have a project in which I am trying to run a GitHub action to get the coverage and work out what lines of code haven't been tested as the logic is complex. I can't work out how to export a pdf file that contains the information.
Currently, I am only getting coverage for the test files:

ConfigManagerTests.cpp
main.cpp

The structure of the project is:
|- project
   |- src
      |- common
      |- common_unittests

Dockerfile:
from  swatkat1977/duplitrace_gtest:NIGHTLY

ARG duplitrace_dir=/duplitrace/
ENV DUPLITRACE_DIR=$duplitrace_dir
ENV DUPLITRACE_OUTDIR=.
ENV GOOGLETEST_INCLUDE=/usr/local/include/
ENV GOOGLETEST_LIB=/usr/local/lib/

RUN groupadd --system duplitrace && \
    useradd --system duplitrace --gid duplitrace && \
    mkdir -p ${DUPLITRACE_DIR} && \
    chown -R duplitrace:duplitrace ${DUPLITRACE_DIR}

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
    apt update && \
    apt-get install --yes lcov && \
    apt-get install --yes gcovr && \
    apt-get install --yes weasyprint

COPY --chown=duplitrace:duplitrace src/3rd_party ${DUPLITRACE_DIR}3rd_party
COPY --chown=duplitrace:duplitrace src/common ${DUPLITRACE_DIR}common
COPY --chown=duplitrace:duplitrace src/common_unittests ${DUPLITRACE_DIR}common_unittests

WORKDIR ${DUPLITRACE_DIR}common_unittests

RUN make clean ; make

CMD ./unittests_common ; \
    lcov --capture --directory ../common --output-file coverage.info ; \
    lcov --remove coverage.info '/usr/include/*' --output-file coverage.filtered.info ; \
    mkdir -p coverage_report ; \
    gcovr -r . --html --html-details --output coverage_report/index.html --exclude-unreachable-branches --exclude-throw-branches ; \
    weasyprint coverage_report/index.html coverage_report.pdf


Finally, the GitHub Action:
name: Unit Tests | Common
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 1 * * *'

  push:
    # Set branch to be invalid on purpose!
    branches:
      - 'invalid'

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      CUR_TIMESTAMP:
        description: Timestamp for the build
        required: false
        # Leave empty; we'll set it programmatically if not provided
        default: ''

jobs:
  run_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-24.04
    steps:

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Login to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@v3
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Build Docker image
        run: |
          docker buildx build --load -f docker/Dockerfile.unittests_common -t unittests_common:latest .

      - name: Debug List Docker images
        run: |
          docker images

      - name: Run Docker container
        run: |
          docker run --name unittests_common unittests_common:latest

      - name: Copy covergage pdf from QEMU instance
        run: |
          docker cp unittests_common:/duplitrace/common_unittests/coverage_report.pdf ./common_unittests_coverage.pdf

      - name: Upload pdf as artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: common_unittests_coverage.pdf
          path: common_unittests_coverage.pdf

